# perl regex of exactly 10 characters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm using perl flavored regexes in PHP with the `preg_match` function. I want to validate a key that is exactly 10 characters, with upper case alpha characters or numbers.

I have

```
preg_match( '/[^A-Z0-9]/', $key);
```

which finds invalid characters next to valid ones. In my limited knowledge, I tried

```
preg_match( '/[^A-Z0-9]{10}$/', $key);
```

which turns out to match *all* my test strings, even the invalid ones.

How do I specify this regular expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've misplaced the `^` character which anchors the beginning of a string. `/[^A-Z0-9]{10}$/` would match all files ending on 10 characters that are not uppercase letters and digits.

The correct RE would be:

```
preg_match( '/^[A-Z0-9]{10}$/', $key);
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- `^` - matches from the beginning of the string

  - `[` - begin of a character class, a character should match against these. If a `^` is found straight after this `[`, it negates the match

    - `A-Z` - uppercase letters
    - `0-9` - digits
  - `]` - end of a character class
  - `{10}` - matches the previous character class 10 times
- `$` - matches the string till the end

Comment: Ah! I see what I did. When I started writing it, I intended to check for any *invalid* character (and return false). Then I wanted to ensure it was 10 characters long. Is there any way to write the regex to check for *invalid* characters **and** make sure the string is 10 characters long?

Comment: `/^[^a-z]{10}$/` will match 10 digit strings that don't have any lowercase characters.

Comment: @Jacob yeah, but I need it to throw out any non-alphanumerics, too.

Comment: @user151841: if you want to return on strings that contain invalid characters or do not have a length of 10, use the `!` to negate the return value. I.e. `if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]{10}$/')) return false;`

Comment: This should work for anything that in not a lowercase and not a non-word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and not an _ `/^[^a-z\W_]{10}$/`

Comment: @Lekensteyn Sorry you're mistaken. I've tested `/^[^a-z\W_]{10}$/` successfully [here](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php) against strings such as `ASDFAS_FA8` `ASDFAS#FA8` `ASDFASFFA8` `asfdasdf89` and `ASDFASDFASDF`

Comment: @Jacob: oops, my fault. I've misinterpreted the results from my functions.